# What lib or software to sign and verify blindly?

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, blind-signature

I recently heard of blind signatures. I saw the wikipedia article on how they work but don't feel like implementing it. What libraries (preferably compatible with linux and windows) may I use to implement blind signatures and verifying the file is signed?

I tried looking at openssl man pages but I don't think it supports blind signatures http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/dgst.html

I can implement my app in either C++ or .NET and have no issues spawning process and parsing their outputs however a lib would be preferred over software.

Comment: What do you need blind signatures for ?

Answer (score 1):

> I can implement my app in either C++ or .NET ... What lib or software to sign and verify blindly?

Here's a [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) based answer.  Crypto++ is a class library of cryptographic schemes written by Wei Dai.  The example was taken from [Raw RSA | Blind Signatures](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA#RSA_Blind_Signature) on the wiki.

Jack Lloyd's [Botan](https://github.com/randombit/botan), which is a C++11 crypto and TLS library, may have native blind signature support.

Crypto++ lacks blind signature classes. The method below follows the basic algorithm as detailed at [Blind Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature). However, it differs from Wikipedia by applying the `s(s'(x)) = x` cross-check. The cross-check was present in [Chaum's original paper](http://www.hit.bme.hu/~buttyan/courses/BMEVIHIM219/2009/Chaum.BlindSigForPayment.1982.PDF), but it is missing from the wiki article. A second difference from Chaum's paper and wikipedia is, the code below uses `H(m)` rather than `m`. That's due to [Rabin in 1979](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf).

You may want to apply a padding function first per [Usability of padding scheme in blinded RSA signature?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12707/10496) or [RSA blind signatures in practice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5626/10496). Also see [Is there a standard padding/format for RSA Blind Signatures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54085/10496)

---

```cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "integer.h"
#include "nbtheory.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "rsa.h"
#include "sha.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::runtime_error;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Bob artificially small key pair
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    RSA::PrivateKey privKey;

    privKey.GenerateRandomWithKeySize(prng, 64);
    RSA::PublicKey pubKey(privKey);

    // Convenience
    const Integer& n = pubKey.GetModulus();
    const Integer& e = pubKey.GetPublicExponent();
    const Integer& d = privKey.GetPrivateExponent();

    // Print params
    cout << "Pub mod: " << std::hex << pubKey.GetModulus() << endl;
    cout << "Pub exp: " << std::hex << e << endl;
    cout << "Priv mod: " << std::hex << privKey.GetModulus() << endl;
    cout << "Priv exp: " << std::hex << d << endl;

    // For sizing the hashed message buffer. This should be SHA256 size.
    const size_t SIG_SIZE = UnsignedMin(SHA256::BLOCKSIZE, n.ByteCount());

    // Scratch
    SecByteBlock buff1, buff2, buff3;

    // Alice original message to be signed by Bob
    SecByteBlock orig((const byte*)"secret", 6);
    Integer m(orig.data(), orig.size());
    cout << "Message: " << std::hex << m << endl;

    // Hash message per Rabin (1979)
    buff1.resize(SIG_SIZE);
    SHA256 hash1;
    hash1.CalculateTruncatedDigest(buff1, buff1.size(), orig, orig.size());

    // H(m) as Integer
    Integer hm(buff1.data(), buff1.size());
    cout << "H(m): " << std::hex << hm << endl;

    // Alice blinding
    Integer r;
    do {
        r.Randomize(prng, Integer::One(), n - Integer::One());
    } while (!RelativelyPrime(r, n));

    // Blinding factor
    Integer b = a_exp_b_mod_c(r, e, n);
    cout << "Random: " << std::hex << b << endl;

    // Alice blinded message
    Integer mm = a_times_b_mod_c(hm, b, n);
    cout << "Blind msg: " << std::hex << mm << endl;

    // Bob sign
    Integer ss = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, mm);
    cout << "Blind sign: " << ss << endl;

    // Alice checks s(s'(x)) = x. This is from Chaum's paper
    Integer c = pubKey.ApplyFunction(ss);
    cout << "Check sign: " << c << endl;
    if (c != mm)
        throw runtime_error("Alice cross-check failed");

    // Alice remove blinding
    Integer s = a_times_b_mod_c(ss, r.InverseMod(n), n);
    cout << "Unblind sign: " << s << endl;

    // Eve verifies
    Integer v = pubKey.ApplyFunction(s);    
    cout << "Verify: " << std::hex << v << endl;

    // Convert to a string
    size_t req = v.MinEncodedSize();
    buff2.resize(req);
    v.Encode(&buff2[0], buff2.size());

    // Hash message per Rabin (1979)
    buff3.resize(SIG_SIZE);
    SHA256 hash2;
    hash2.CalculateTruncatedDigest(buff3, buff3.size(), orig, orig.size());

    // Constant time compare
    bool equal = buff2.size() == buff3.size() && VerifyBufsEqual(
        buff2.data(), buff3.data(), buff3.size());

    if (!equal)
        throw runtime_error("Eve verified failed");

    cout << "Verified signature" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of building and running the program:

```
$ g++ blind.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o blind.exe
$ ./blind.exe
Pub mod: bbf62585f8486acbh
Pub exp: 11h
Priv mod: bbf62585f8486acbh
Priv exp: 31c1280c6bb08635h
Message: 736563726574h
H(m): 2bb80d537b1da3e3h
Random: 7db0ecdb0a09fad5h
Blinded msg: a8bf62a25b7b4b53h
Blind sign: 2646ab6b9d5b48dfh
Check sign: a8bf62a25b7b4b53h
Unblind sign: 418d211b9cbb2d00h
Verify: 2bb80d537b1da3e3h
Verified signature
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need any special support for blind signatures. You simply need to be able to sign and verify a message. The blind part is up to the system using the asymmetric cipher. Simply signing content you receive in a special format could constitute blind signing, indicating the data passed through you before going somewhere else. [Just make sure you don't use RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature#Dangers_of_blind_signing)

**EDIT**

As per the extended discussion in this answer's comments, the above text may be misleading depending on what you are speaking of specifically. If you intend to complete blind signing as described in the comments to this answer, then you will in fact need special support. I would say if you can't find something reviewed and tested, it would be a cool exercise or project to implement your own and post it on GitHub or the like.

Comment: 1) Which blind signature besides RSA would you use? All other blind signature algos (e.g. Lucre) are much more complicated and weird. 2) blind RSA signatures are secure when used properly. Linked attack requires improper use. 3) For blind RSA signatures you need a special API, since the standard APIs apply both padding and exponentiation in one step, whereas with blind signatures they need to be performed separately. 4) The rest of the post makes even less sense, but I don't really understand what you want to say there. Normal signature algorithms obviously aren't blinded.

Comment: @CodesInChaos There is no truly correct form for blind signatures. Any algorithm can be used in blind signing. All you need to do in order to perform blind signing is to accept messages, sign them, and verify signed messages. In your comment, point #2 has no information, only your statement. Point #3 is silly because of what I already stated here. As for point #1, the most important, I would use traditional RSA with padding; messages would be in a special form and encrypted using an independent symmetric key to make it actually blind. Blind signatures are useful for proving a chain of handoffs

Comment: I totally don't get how you could use any algorithm for blind signatures. The important part of a blind signature is that it's impossible to link the final signature with the signature request. This means the message seen when signing and the message seen when verifying must not have any discernible relation unless you know the secret blinding value. Simply signing an encrypted message doesn't have that unlinkability property.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If you say that in order for a blind signature to be created, one must never know who requested the signature to be made, then it is impossible to design such a system on the basis that the original signer will be signing it and has to receive it from someone, who they could later identify. I am saying the original individual can simply digitally sign something (or not, depending on requirements), encrypt it, pass it along to someone else to digitally sign, and so on. An encrypted envelope if you will, which is then signed in succession by all parties interacting with it.

Comment: You have three parties: requester, signer, verifier. The requester does the blinding/unblinding and can link the request and signature. But signer and verifier cannot link the signature request and the signature even when the cooperate. This requires special math, such as RSA blinding as described on wikipedia. You can even have multiple parties doing the blinding, so in the end nobody can link. With your scheme they can trivially link it, since the signature request contains encrypted message (or its hash), and the hash in the signature signature directly matches that ciphertext.

Comment: In your description, the requestor can link the signature and the signature request in addition to the signer linking the signature and the signature request. The signer needs to get the request at some point, blinded or not. Encryption and blinding both only prevent the signer from knowing the contents and not who requested the data to be signed in the first place. A ciphertext only directly matches some content directly when the key is known, similar to your blinding value. Anyway, this is getting a little long winded, so you're welcome to your down vote but I disagree with it.

Comment: The signer signed the blinded token, but when verifying the signature you're working with the unblinded token. It is not possible to see that those are related. The only thing you see is that the unblinded token is a valid signature. To accomplish this seemingly impossible property, you need special algorithms which are different from standard algorithms. For a practical example you can look at Chaum's ecash where it's impossible to link the spending and redemption part of a transaction.

Comment: With your scheme, when one signs a ciphertext, that produces a signature that can only be verified by looking at the ciphertext. With a blind signature, ones signs the ciphertext, but the signature is valid on the plaintext, not the ciphertext. You could look at this [presentation about the basics of blind signatures](http://www.slideshare.net/kelumkps/blind-signature-scheme) or at Chaum's original paper, it's relatively easy to read as well.

Comment: Read through it, seems familiar. I still hold that "blind signing" is not well defined enough to say that either this scheme or the one I described is correct in this case. I will agree that in the future I will be using the definition based on the presentation you provided, as it is more useful. Though there are still faults with it, especially concerning the signing of content you're unsure of and also the blinding attack against RSA.

Comment: The main consequence of the blinding attack against RSA is that you must not use one `(e,n)` pair for both encryption and blind signatures. I believe it's possible to reuse an `n` as long as you choose co-prime `e`s. This kind of signature is mainly useful if all that matters is how many signatures you have obtained, not what they contain. e.g. because each correctly padded signature with unique serial is worth a certain amount of money, as in Chaum's ecash. It's certainly not a general purpose signature scheme.